# Can't reference TextView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing my first ever Android App using Eclipse.

I have the following code for my `activity_main.xml` view:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="biztalkers.gcmtest3.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtToken"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I have the following code within my MainActivity.java class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView txtToken = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtToken);
```

My problem is with tha last line in the code block `"final TextView txtToken = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtToken);"`, for this I get the error `"txtToken cannot be resolved or is not a field"`. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Here are the imports

```
package biztalkers.gcmtest3;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import biztalkers.gcmtest3.R;
```

The line "import biztalkers.gcmtest3.R;" is underlined red as it "cannot be resolved"

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: If you have an error in one of your `res` folders, your R.java file will not get generated.

Comment: Thanks dcharms, this was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to dcharms. The problem was due to an error in one of the res files

Answer (score 2):

Clean and re-build your project like this,

Project -> Clean -> Check your project and press OK.

Also verify your imports.. If you have `import android.R` delete it.. You should only import R with the package like `import com.example.R`

Comment: He didn't. he posted the answer before you!!! So according to me you stole his answer.

Comment: @Rajendra no, he edited his answer after I posted mine

Comment: Ohh.. Then his fault not you!!@IanNewson

Comment: @IanNewson Whoops.. I didn't see your answer.. I just replied to this question as I have faced the same problem before. Also the answer to the question is a very general one.. there is nothing to copy here.. It is not fair to downvote my answer.. hope you understand!! Cheers :)

Comment: After project clean, I deleted the import android.R, now I get "R cannot be resolved to a variable". I have package biztalkers.gcmtest3; It won't accept import biztalkers.gcmtest3.R

Comment: @RobBowman You have to import your R as a `com.yourpackagename.R`

Answer (score 0):

Simply save every files in your project.Because `R.java` will be modified at the time of saving.Now you may have a `TextView` in your layout.But , that will not be updated in the project....

Answer (score 0):

Retry by changing the id of the TextView with a new id and also clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score -1):

Check your import statements. Make sure you haven't imported the android R class (i.e. `import android.R`) instead of your own projects R class.